# XML emitted from PHP does not show correctly in IE 10 source view

Tags: php, xml, encoding, utf-8

I try to emit an XML document from a PHP (engine is 5.3) script. The page displays correctly in IE 10 and Firefox. I can see the XML tree as I do not use a stylesheet. I can also see the raw XML in the source view of Firefox. However, if I Display the source code in IE 10, it shows as a bunch of Japanese characters (although the rendering is correct). IE shows the page encoding as UNICODE, not UTF-8, while Firefox shows UTF-8.

In the PHP script, I emit as first line `header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');` and the first line of the XML document is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`.

I presume that I have some kind of hidden encoding issue, but I have not idea how to troubleshoot it. Any suggestions on how I can find the reason for this behaviour?

Thanks in advance,
Christoph

Comment: Fetch the page with curl, and use the file command to analyze and check with iconv for invalid utf-8 sequences (it will tell you so). you can check that in a matter of seconds this way.

Comment: I like that idea. Seems that the file has a BOM which might be the problem. If you posted an answer, I would accept it...